# StatusBar behavior reset after moving to other webpage

Tags: cordova

I'm using Cordova with statusbar plugin.

When my app launches, the status bar is as I specified it to be - not overlapping and with a background color I chose (in a preference tag in config.xml).

The problem is when I navigate to another webpage:

```
[self.viewController.webViewEngine loadRequest:myRequest]
```

The navigation happens but the status bar is reset and is overlapping the view.
How can I fix this? Am I doing the navigation correctly?

Thanks.